# If you don’t want Eloquent to automatically manage created_at and updated_at columns, which of the following will be correct?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

1. Set the model `$timestamps` property to `false`.
2. Eloquent will always automatically manage `created_at` and `updated_at`
   columns.
3. Set the model `$created_at` and `updated_at` properties to `false`.

I searched the net and found a lot of solution and what must be the real answer to this question,

I found that we can disable it add a line into the eloquent to make timestamp false

```
class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

But we can also remove the `created_at` and `updated_at` and do not use it in the model so 3rd point is also true here?

So what is the proper solution for this question?

Comment: Remove timestamps in Migration. If table exist delete timestamps columns and set Model timestamps false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should set the `$timestamps` property to `false` in your model. and not add the timestamp columns (`$table->timestamps();`) in your table migration.